# MySQL id and corresponding sequence join

Tags: mysql, join

I have 2 tables which utilize the same two fields, an ID number and a sequence number. Table one (Order Table) holds the Value of an item and table two (Adjustments Table) holds the any adjustments associated (tax, discount, etc..). So I need to get into a report, the ID, the corresponding sequences, the individual values and the adjustments.
As of right now when I write the query, I can't get it to separate the the values based on order ID and the corresponding sequence id

Here is my query which is wrong.

```
select Adjustments, OT.*
from order_table OT
join (select AT2.order_sequence, SUM(AT2.value) as Adjustments, AT2.id
  from adjustment_table AT2
  group by AT2.id
) AT on AT.id = OT.id
```

---

```
Order Table

ID    |ORDER_SEQUENCE |PRICE    
10001 |01             |20
10001 |02             |30
10001 |03             |40
10002 |01             |20
10002 |02             |10
10003 |01             |25
10004 |01             |35
10005 |01             |40
10005 |02             |20
10005 |03             |10
10005 |04             |30
10006 |01             |20


Adjustment Table

ID    |ORDER_SEQUENCE|VALUE   |ADJUSTMENT_TYPE
10001 |01            |2       |Tax
10001 |01            |-5      |Discount
10001 |01            |-.5     |Post Discount Tax Adjustment
10001 |02            |3       |Tax
10001 |03            |4       |Tax
10001 |03            |-10     |Discount
10001 |03            |-1      |Post Discount Tax Adjustment
10002 |01            |2       |Tax
10002 |02            |1       |Tax
10003 |01            |2.5     |Tax
10003 |01            |-6.25   |Discount
10003 |01            |-.63    |Post Discount Tax Adjustment
10004 |01            |3.5     |Tax
10004 |01            |-8.75   |Discount
10004 |01            |-.88    |Post Discount Tax Adjustment
10005 |01            |4       |Tax
10005 |01            |-10     |Discount
10005 |01            |-1      |Post Discount Tax Adjustment
10005 |02            |2       |Tax
10005 |02            |-5      |Discount
10005 |02            |-.5     |Post Discount Tax Adjustment
10005 |03            |1       |Tax
10005 |04            |3       |Tax
10006 |01            |2       |Tax


Results I need
ID    |ORDER_SEQUENCE |PRICE    |Total Adjustments
10001 |01             |20       |-3.5
10001 |02             |30       |3
10001 |03             |40       |-7
10002 |01             |20       |2
10002 |02             |10       |1
10003 |01             |25       |-4.38
10004 |01             |35       |-6.13
10005 |01             |40       |-7
10005 |02             |20       |-3.50
10005 |03             |10       |1
10005 |04             |30       |3
10006 |01             |20       |2
```

Comment: Looks like you just need to add `order_sequence` to both the `GROUP BY` and the `ON`. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should get better performance without a subquery:

```
   SELECT ot.id, 
          ot.order_sequence,
          ot.price,
          COALESCE(SUM(at.value),0) adjustments
     FROM order_table ot
LEFT JOIN adjustment_table at
       ON at.id = ot.id
      AND at.order_sequence = ot.order_sequence
 GROUP BY ot.id, ot.order_sequence, ot.price
 ORDER BY ot.id, ot.order_sequence
```

I used a `LEFT JOIN` and `COALESCE` to give you adjustments of `0` if there are no adjustments for that combination.

You can even include the total with:

```
   SELECT ot.id, 
          ot.order_sequence,
          ot.price,
          COALESCE(SUM(at.value),0) adjustments,
          ot.price + COALESCE(SUM(at.value),0) total
     FROM order_table ot
LEFT JOIN adjustment_table at
       ON at.id = ot.id
      AND at.order_sequence = ot.order_sequence
 GROUP BY ot.id, ot.order_sequence, ot.price
 ORDER BY ot.id, ot.order_sequence
```

Comment: The second one really helped me, I'm still getting the hang of this seeing good work helps me along.

Comment: @user3576403 You were pretty close anyway.. that's why I didn't bother  explaining in too much detail. Happy to help :)

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add `order_sequence` to the grouping and join condition.

```
select Adjustments, OT.*
from order_table OT
join (select AT2.order_sequence, SUM(AT2.value) as Adjustments, AT2.id
    from adjustment_table AT2
    group by AT2.id, AT2.order_sequence) AT 
on AT.id = OT.id AND AT.order_sequence = OT.order_sequence
order by OT.id, OT.order_sequence
```

[DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/00b8d/1)